# how to power save and lookup power usage in terminal

Tags: battery

I have already installed  powertop , pm-utils , laptop-mode-tool , jupitor  , also power save with jupitor , cpu-frequency skilling powersave , pm-powersave true but power usage are 1 hour and 20 minutes on 50 percentage of battery , at least 130 minutes in window seven .

Ubuntu 12.04.3 kernel 3.8 
,lenovo z400
,ivy i5-3230 M
,nvidia 740m with Intel 4000.

Comment: i already use powertop , i run my battery with pm-powersave yes , cpu-freq powersave , jupiter powersave , but the power is not more than window power usage , now my ubuntu power consuming are 1 hour 20 minutes , the window are  around 2 hour and 20 minutes .

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu having two power tools which can work efficiently through terminal and can give you complete information about your power statistics, they are powetop and powerstat. you can install them with

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
```

&

```
sudo apt-get install powerstat
```

To run powertop you must be root user , so run it as sudo.I mean

```
sudo powertop
```

Then you will see ( captured in my PC , usually No battery :P , just for Idea )

[image]

powerstat you can run as normal user also , it will provide the complete status information of the battery.

hope that helps you about Command line power monitoring tools.